# retuning conditional children not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript

my header:

```
<header className="app-header">
        {newChildren && <ModalLogin isModal={modalActive} closePop={closePop} children={newChildren} />}
        <HeaderPublic schema={HeaderPublicLinkSchema} />
      </header>
```

where I am setting `newChildren` for tempate.

on click of either login or register, I am trying to switch the `children`. but not works;

here is the function for click event.

```
const [modalActive, setModalActive] = useState(false);
  let newChildren: ReactElement | undefined = undefined;
  const openPop = (temp: string) => {
    console.log('temp', temp);
    if (temp === 'register') {
      newChildren = <FormRegister closePop={closePop} registerSubmit={onRegisterSubmit} />;
    }
    if (temp === 'login') {
      newChildren = newChildren = <FormLogin />;
    }
    setModalActive(true);
  };
```

Not able to understand the issue. any one help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so `openPop` gets called, sets a local variable `newChildren` to some components, and calls a `state` setter `setModalActive` which   will immediately trigger a re-render.

Once it re-renders, your `let newChildren` is `undefined`. I think this is a classic mistake trying to use `let vars` + mutation like vanilla JS as a way to store state, and have some click/etc handler modify it. You can't do that in a function component because they are "pure" -- called per render, no local state stored, except for the `useState`, `useRef` etc return values.

If you have data that you want to persist between renders, use additional `state`. You can't use `let` and hope those values persist via changing them via a click handler.

More concretely, whenever you are tempted to use `let x`, use state:

```
const [newChildren, setNewChildren] = useState()
```

The only time `let x` and conditional reassignment to it will persist through output is if that assignment is made during render and not during an event.

Basically, think of any time you call `setState` as calling your function anew and all of the implications of that.